# C# CF - Convert a SOAP Message from a Stream

Tags: c#, compact-framework, soap-client

I have a Windows mobile .NET 3.5 compact framework application on a handheld device which connects to a SOAP Server requiring WS-Security in the message header.

Since WSE doesn't work on compact framework, I managed to create a Custom Binding to communicate with the server and receive messages.

In the Custom Binding Encoder (a MessageEncoder), I need to override some methods to read the received message :

```
public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
{
    bufferManager.ReturnBuffer(buffer.Array);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, buffer.Count);
    // to quickly see the content of the message
    string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, buffer.Array.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("gna " + s);
    Message message = this.ReadMessage(memoryStream, buffer.Array.Length, null);
    return message;
}

public override Message ReadMessage(Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
    return Message.CreateMessage(reader, maxSizeOfHeaders, this.MessageVersion);
}
```

**The second method doesn't compile in compact framework!** According to [the definition of the `CreateMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.createmessage(v=vs.90).aspx) method, compact framework allows only a few possibilities : using a `BodyWriter` or a `XmlObjectSerializer` instead of simply using a `XmlReader` as provided in the above standard code. The problem is that these two objects are abstract and need to be instanciated in order to be used by the function.

**So is there some way to create a Message from a Stream in compact framework?** Did somebody have the same problem? Are there any pre-build objects I can use to replace these `BodyWriter` or `XmlObjectSerializer`?